# Problema al hacer deploy de proyecto

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, base-de-datos

Desarrolle un proyecto el cual cuenta con

- Back / NodeJS
- Front / ReactJS

El mismo lo acabo de montar en el servidor de la empresa el cual posee la ip http://192.168.100.11:3000 / Desde ahi me abre el sitio de forma corercta

Mi problema es con la base de datos, no se coencta y por lo que veo es porque tengo configurada mi BD de la siguiente forma

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const dbConnect = () => {
    const DB_URI = process.env.DB_URI;
    mongoose.connect(DB_URI, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    },(err, res) => {
        if(!err){
            console.log('*** DB Connected ***');
        }else{
            console.log('*** DB Error connected ***');
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
}

module.exports = dbConnect;
```

Donde las variables de env son las siguientes

- APP_PORT=3001
- DB_URI=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/nic-app

De manera local, cuando ingreso al servidor funciona todo correcto. El tema es cuando quiero acceder desde otra maquina de la red.

Cuando ingreso a la IP y trato de loguearme me tira error y es porque me esta tratando de tomar una base de datos en el localhost de esa maquina y no la del servidor.

Que configuración debo aplicar para que la base de datos que tome sea la del servidor y no la de la maquina por la cual estoy accediendo

Comment: ¿Has intentado utilizar la IP de red? Tené en cuenta que si tenes firewall vas a necesitar habilitar el puerto para que puedan conectarse.

Comment: Es que cambie a DB_URI=mongodb://192.168.1.100:27017/nic-app pero cuando hago node index no me levanta porque no se conecta a la base de datos. Porque la app se encuentra corriendo en el servidor. No en una maquina externa

Comment: ¿Que sistema operativo estas usando? Revisa estos links: [Archivo de configuracion](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) y [Asignar un IP](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/)

Comment: Windows 10. El tema es como configuro mi proyecto de nodejs o mi mongo db para que levante de forma correcta?

Comment: Proba agregar a MongoDb Server la IP de red. Busca el archivo de configuración y proba poner `bindIp: "127.0.0.1,192.168.1.100"`. Una vez que te puedas conectar al servidor utilizando la IP de red, despues necesitar ver si desde OTRA máquina de la red también podes, ahí es cuando vas a tener que ver la configuración del firewall